# How to open Spacemacs/emacsclient from Mac Spotlight

Tags: spacemacs, osx

This is more of a Mac question, than emacs. I think, this is relevant to this site.

I have emacs (Spacemacs) installed via brew, and I can invoke it from a terminal. However, I wish to invoke `emacs --daemon` and `emacsclient -nc` from the *spotlight* of Mac, that I often use to launch programs.

Does anyone do it? How do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

1. Open `Automator`.
2. Create new file as an `Application`.
3. Add a `Run Shell Script` step.
4. Paste the following as the content of the shell script:

   ```
   /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient \
     --no-wait \
     --quiet \
     --suppress-output \
     --create-frame \
     .
   ```
5. Save the file as `Emacsclient.app` under the `/Applications` folder.

Thanks to [luke-francl](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/16122/luke-francl) for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about invoking an emacsclient from Spotlight, but I installed [Emacs for OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com) via homebrew using `brew cask install emacs` and it installs a proper `.app` file so you can launch Emacs from Spotlight.

Prior to discovering Emacs for OS X, I created an Automator application that runs a shell script to launch Emacs. I named the Automator application `Emacs.app` so that Spotlight could find it. You might be able to use that for invoking emacsclient.

Comment: Thanks! I think, Automator might be a way for me. Do you have Automator recipe to open a command line application. I tried few things for 10 minutes and couldn't get to anywhere.

Comment: I used something like Automator Application > Run Shell Script then set `open /path/to/emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` as the script. [This blog post has an example of using emacsclient](http://dlukes.github.io/emacs-daemon-osx.html) so might be closer to what you want.